# how to insert push notification payload into database when app is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, background-fetch

How to insert the push notification payload data into database when app is in background. I tried the content-available tag but it doesn't work for me.
Please help me out

Comment: check my answer !!

Comment: when app is on foreground control come to this function. But when app is in background control is not coming to function.

Answer (score 1):

content-available tag also required and use this method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    //add notification data to your database here

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

And add this to your xcode.

[image]